# hive load external table from dynamic location(partitioned)

Tags: hive, hiveql, external-tables

I need to create a hive table(external) to load data generated by another process. I need to be partitioned by date, But the problem is, there is a random string in the path.

Example input paths :

```
/user/hadoop/output/FDQM9N4RCQ3V2ZYT/20170314/
/user/hadoop/output/FDPWMUVVBO2X74CA/20170315/
/user/hadoop/output/FDPGNC0ENA6QOF9G/20170316/
.........
.........
```

Here 4th field in the directory is dynamic(which cannot be guessed). Each of these directories will have multiple .gz files

What location would I give while creating the table?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user (
userId BIGINT,
type INT,
date String
)
PARTITIONED BY (date String)
LOCATION '/user/hadoop/output/';
```

is this correct? if so how do I partition it based on the date(last field in the directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using the partition convention you'll have to add each partition manually.

- The table location does not matter, but for clarity leave it as it is now.
- I would recommend to use `date` type for the partition or at least the ISO format, `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- I would not use `date` as a column name (nor `int`,`string` etc.).

---

```
PARTITIONED BY (dt date)
```

---

```
alter table user add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-03-14') location '/user/hadoop/output/FDQM9N4RCQ3V2ZYT/20170314';
alter table user add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-03-15') location '/user/hadoop/output/FDPWMUVVBO2X74CA/20170315';
alter table user add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-03-16') location '/user/hadoop/output/FDPGNC0ENA6QOF9G/20170316';
```

Comment: Thank you Dudu Markovitz